# remote debugging application code(eclipse-test-plugin) in eclipse IDE via maven build not working

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, remote-debugging

- **Background :**
  We have an eclipse RCP application with a set of plugin projects & each with a test fragment.

Been looking into an issue where couple of test cases are failing on the build system(via Jenkins build) but passing locally when run as JUNIT5 tests!

The test case failure is locally replicable when I run maven build on the test plugin.

- **Issue:**
  I want to remotely debug the test cases via maven build for which I followed a few online links & SO threads:
  [Debugging Junit tests from Maven project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578648/debugging-junit-tests-from-maven-project-in-eclipse)
  https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/how-to-debug-a-test-run-with-maven/

The solution given there doesn't work for me as the build is not suspending.

Any leads or help in this would be life saving folks!

[Debugging Junit tests from Maven project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578648/debugging-junit-tests-from-maven-project-in-eclipse)
https://doc.nuxeo.com/corg/how-to-debug-a-test-run-with-maven/

Comment: For a [plugin test you have to set `-DdebugPort=...`](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#debug-maven-tycho-tests-via-eclipse) instead of `-Dmaven.surefire.debug`. See also https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md#automatically-launch-and-attach-remote-application-debugger-when-maven-plug-in-starts-a-forked-jvm-that-waits-for-a-debugger

Comment: Start your test case from your IDE...

Comment: Unfortunately "-Dmaven.surefire.debug" also didn't work, the maven build doesn't suspend

Comment: Yes, I told you so: `-Dmaven.surefire.debug` does not work for remote debugging Eclipse plugin tests. Maven Surefire and Tycho Surefire are different things. Maven Surefire is only capable to run plain JUnit tests, not Eclipse plugin tests. For Eclipse plugin tests, you need to set `-DdebugPort=...` to a port number, e.g. `-DdebugPort=8000`.